# Write a function with fewer rows of command

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've create a function "cross2" for complete a matrix with a random sampling of two numbers from the two previous columns for complete the two following columns. But when a number is sampled, the other number sampled is on another line.

```
#I create the matrix "tab2"
data2=np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]) 
data22=data2.transpose()
tab2=np.zeros((6,8),float)
tab2[:,0:2]=data22

def cross2 (a):#a is the column of the data
    for i in range (0,6):#i is the row of the data
        number=np.arange(0,6,1)
        c=np.random.choice(number,1,replace=True)
        tab2[i,a]=tab2[c,a-2]# select a number by a random choice from second previous column
        toChooseFrom1 = np.concatenate((tab2[:c,(a-2)], tab2[(c+1):,(a-2)]))
        toChooseFrom2 = np.concatenate((tab2[:c,(a-1)], tab2[(c+1):,(a-1)]))
        tochoose=np.concatenate([toChooseFrom1,toChooseFrom2])
        np.random.shuffle(tochoose)
        tab2[i,a+1]=np.random.choice(tochoose,1,replace=True)

#loop to complete the matrix tab2 with the function "cross2"
for a in range (2,8):
    if a % 2 ==0:
        cross2(a)
```

I think this function is good but I would like do the same thing with fewer lines, if it's possible, because I have a long script.

Comment: If this is **working code** see [codereview.se].

Comment: " I would like do the same thing with fewer lines, if it's possible, because I have a long script.". In which case, a few lines more or less shouldn't really matter.